# How to fetch location from mongodb based on latitude and longitude using Laravel eloquent?

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel

I am using [Moloquent](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb) model for fetching data from MongoDB in Laravel.

Everything was fine except getting data based on latitude and longitude. This is how my collection looks:

```
{
   "_id" : "some_id",
   "place_id" : "353789030392849490",
   "latitude": "22.5726",
   "longitude" : "88.3639"
}
```

In MySQL and Laravel Eloquent, we can fetch data using latitude and longitude like this:

```
DB:select("SELECT id, (
    6371 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) 
    * cos( radians( long ) - radians(-122) )
    + sin( radians(37) ) * sin(radians(lat)) )
) AS distance 
FROM myTable
HAVING distance < 50
ORDER BY distance")->get();
```

Can I do the same using Laravel Eloquent to fetch data from MongoDB? Or do I need to do it in some other way?

PS. I am new to MongoDB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like the following as stated in the `README.md` of [laravel-mongodb](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb):

```
$users = User::where('location', 'near', [
    '$geometry' => [
        'type' => 'Point',
        'coordinates' => [
            -0.1367563,
            51.5100913,
        ],
    ],
    '$maxDistance' => 50,
]);
```

> NOTE: Specify coordinates in this order: longitude, latitude.

Your collection should have a `2dsphere` index: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/2dsphere/

An example of a collection:

```
{
    loc : { type: "Point", coordinates: [ -73.97, 40.77 ] },
    name: "Central Park",
    category : "Parks"
}
```

For more information about the `$near`: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/2dsphere/

Comment: How should I structure my collection in first hand, so that this query could execute?

Comment: Thanks. Let me check it tomorrow while in Office. But anyhow, thanks Sir.

Comment: yes Sir. This worked exactly the way I wanted. Thanks a lot Sir. :)